# Is there any neurological research on schema theory?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, perception

I noticed schema theory is frequently mentioned in educational psychology and sociocultural topics but didn't find neurological research related to it. I wonder if there are some shared mechanisms between prototype and schema. Currently, I'm looking for low-level evidence about how people recognize representations or patterns and want to know if there are any neurological studies about schema (or if is there any term in neurology that conveys a similar meaning, like grandma cell).
Thanks!

Comment: Pattern recognition and its abstraction are easier to study in *artificial neural networks (ANNs),* and there is likely plenty of overlap with such findings and the equivalent phenomena in organic neural networks; but it could be interesting to see how human brains handle schemas -- especially higher ones. Obviously some low-level schemas (*image schemas*) have been observed and inferred with respect to the processing that occurs in the layers of the [visual cortex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_cortex). But these are more *implicit* (yet perhaps calibrated) than cognitive or learned.

Comment: @Michael thank you, that's very useful. I have heard much ongoing research in the machine learning area related to functions that humans can perform. However, I don't know how can those studies be applied to psychology studies since those algorithms are designed to resolve imperfection but for psychological mechanisms, we need to find the mechanism that explain the imperfection.